# Ethernet not working, Wi-Fi works normally

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet

```
$ nmcli
enp7s0: connected to Wired connection 1
        "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411"
        ethernet (r8169), F8:75:A4:66:B9:DA, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 192.168.1.10/24
        route4 192.168.1.0/24 metric 100
        route4 default via 192.168.1.1 metric 100
        route4 169.254.0.0/16 metric 1000
        inet6 fe80::19f7:d285:68c8:9100/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024

wlp0s20f3: connected to Euphoria
        "Intel Cannon Lake PCH CNVi"
        wifi (iwlwifi), 60:F2:62:73:CD:8C, hw, mtu 1500
        inet4 192.168.1.14/24
        route4 192.168.1.0/24 metric 600
        route4 default via 192.168.1.1 metric 600
        inet6 fdd8:2918:fbc8:a400:2e06:7b82:bf45:9498/64
        inet6 fdd8:2918:fbc8:a400:b0c5:ac74:e7cd:c270/64
        inet6 fe80::d074:1e18:3146:73a8/64
        route6 fe80::/64 metric 1024
        route6 fdd8:2918:fbc8:a400::/64 metric 600

lo: connected (externally) to lo
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536
        inet4 127.0.0.1/8
        inet6 ::1/128
        route6 ::1/128 metric 256

p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3: disconnected
        "p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3"
        wifi-p2p, hw

DNS configuration:
        servers: 8.8.8.8
        interface: enp7s0

        servers: 192.168.1.1
        domains: home
        interface: wlp0s20f3



nmcli device show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp7s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         F8:75:A4:66:B9:DA
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.10/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::19f7:d285:68c8:9100/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp0s20f3
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         60:F2:62:73:CD:8C
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Euphoria
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.14/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1


ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp7s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f8:75:a4:66:b9:da brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.10/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute enp7s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::19f7:d285:68c8:9100/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:f2:62:73:cd:8c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.14/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp0s20f3
       valid_lft 86067sec preferred_lft 86067sec
    inet6 fdd8:2918:fbc8:a400:2e06:7b82:bf45:9498/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 7142sec preferred_lft 3542sec
    inet6 fdd8:2918:fbc8:a400:b0c5:ac74:e7cd:c270/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 7142sec preferred_lft 3542sec
    inet6 fe80::d074:1e18:3146:73a8/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


ifconfig
enp7s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::19f7:d285:68c8:9100  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f8:75:a4:66:b9:da  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 30  bytes 12167 (12.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 49  bytes 7866 (7.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1666  bytes 221974 (221.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1666  bytes 221974 (221.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp0s20f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.14  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::d074:1e18:3146:73a8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fdd8:2918:fbc8:a400:b0c5:ac74:e7cd:c270  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fdd8:2918:fbc8:a400:2e06:7b82:bf45:9498  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 60:f2:62:73:cd:8c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 367  bytes 63478 (63.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 340  bytes 43790 (43.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
$ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.10 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.10 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.10 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.10 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
25 packets transmitted, 0 received, +24 errors, 100% packet loss, time 24562ms
```

```
$ arp -a
? (192.168.1.9) at 9e:d8:ef:e0:d6:98 [ether] on wlp0s20f3
? (192.168.1.1) at d8:29:18:fb:c8:a4 [ether] on wlp0s20f3
? (192.168.1.1) at <incomplete> on enp7s0
? (192.168.1.9) at <incomplete> on enp7s0
```

Maybe worth noting that Ethernet works just fine on windows. I'm booting off of a usb.

Comment: This line looks odd: `route4 169.254.0.0/16 metric 1000`. Are you on a VPN, or have you somehow set a secondary route for your Ethernet interface? I would investigate that.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I have just set up kubuntu 23.04 and everything is pretty much at default configuration. I am very new to linux.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Do not add your solution to your question. Please add as an answer and select Accepted to indicate it as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Boot into windows, open device manager, open the properties of your ethernet interface (Realtek, etc.), under advanced; choose "Shutdown Wake-On-Lan" and turn that off.

Hope this helps anyone.